# Retain escape character [&quot; &lt; etc..] while copying XML node - Java

Tags: java, xml

I am creating target XML by copying source XML content. I am doing copy at node level. 
Source XML has content with escape character which gets converted [$quot; to " etc...] while I create my target XML

Is there any way to retain original XML content.

Appreciate any help on this.

```
   copyXmlFile("Workflow", "./Source.xml", "./Destination.xml");

   private static void copyXmlFile(String xmlType, String objectSourceFile, String outfile) throws TransformerException {
          //Get the DOM Builder Factory
          DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
          //Get the DOM Builder
          DocumentBuilder builder = null;
          try {
                 builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
          } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }

          //document contains the complete XML as a Tree.
          try {
                 File xmlFileContent = new File(objectSourceFile);
                 Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream(xmlFileContent));

                 // root elements
                 Document documentOut = builder.newDocument();
                 Element rootElementOut = documentOut.createElement(xmlType);
                 rootElementOut.setAttribute("xmlns", "http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata");
                 documentOut.appendChild(rootElementOut);

                 NodeList nodeList = document.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
                 for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
                       Node node = nodeList.item(i);
                       if (node instanceof Element) {    
                              //Node copiedNode = documentOut.importNode(node, true);
                           //rootElementOut.appendChild(copiedNode);
                           rootElementOut.appendChild(documentOut.adoptNode(node.cloneNode(true)));
                       }
                 }

                 // write the content into xml file
                 TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                 Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                 DOMSource source = new DOMSource(documentOut);
                 //StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(outfile));

                 StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
                 StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);

                 transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                 //transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
                 //transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD, "xml");
                 //transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.OMIT_XML_DECLARATION, "yes");
                 transformer.setOutputProperty("{http://xml.apache.org/xslt}indent-amount", "4");
                 transformer.transform(source, result);

                 System.out.println("Escaped XML String in Java: " +  writer.toString());

          } catch (SAXException | IOException e) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                 e.printStackTrace();
          }
   }      }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about how you are doing the copy?

Comment: Are you sure that `&lt;` characters are being emitted as `<`?

Comment: Source XML has content like[&quot;Community Partner&quot;)]. When I copy this to target XML. I don't want conversion [&quot; to "]

Comment: right, my specific question is, does this actually happen for &lt;? My guess is that it does not. And if it doesn't, I have a theory.

Comment: In my source XML - none of the element has [&lt;] as content. Ideally what I want is to copy content as it is i.e. if I have any of these escape character [&lt;, &gt; or &quot;] in my source XML.. I want to copy them as it is in target XML. As as example say <address> element in source is like this <address>&quot;123 &lt; 456 &gt;abc&quot;</address>. I want to copy content of <address> element in its original form to the target xml. At present the content gets copied as ["123<456>abc"].

Comment: The reason I ask is because &lt; and &amp; are the only required entities in XML, and XML processors are *supposed* to interpret entities. So it's not surprising that it parses them on the way in and emits the parsed forms on the way out. So my basic question is, why do you want to keep the entities? The best solution probably depends on your motivation.